# How to declare dependencies on cordova project.properties file?

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, google-play-services, build.gradle

I'm developing an android game with cordova 7.1.0 and I would love to know the meaning of the "+" symbol used on the "cordova_project\platforms\android\project.properties" file. So, what would be the difference between this:

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.0.4
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.0.4
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4
```

And this:

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.0.4+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.0.4+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4+
```

I really want to understand the use of the "+" symbol because after 1st of November I'll not be able to update older versions of my app because they don't target API 26. I don't want my old versions of the app being unable to login to Google Play Games or to stop showing ads.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Gradle, the "**+**" is for **dynamic version of your dependencies**.
Ideally, your builds should be predictable and consistent.

Based from this [blog](https://blog.danlew.net/2015/09/09/dont-use-dynamic-versions-for-your-dependencies/), here are the problems you will encounter if you don't specify your dependency explicitly:

> - Dependencies can unexpectedly introduce behavior changes to your app.
> - The same source built on two different machines can differ.
> - Similarly, builds built on the same machine but at different times can differ.
> - Past builds cannot be reproduced perfectly. This makes it difficult to revert safely.
> - There are security implications if a bad actor introduces a malicious version of a dependency.